# I do not get why the file directory is showing when I start atom live server

Tags: javascript, html, css, atom-editor

I am new to javascript programming and wanted to start off by inserting images. I started off by creating a file for image and another file for my html codes. Then when I started the atom live server it showed me the file directory and when I click on the html file the image is not showing. How do I solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you embedding your script file in your HTML document? If not then you have to embed it in your HTML document so that you can preview it in the browser. To run your code do **Alt + R** if you're using Windows in Atom. Alternatively, you can install it from the command palette by Pressing **Ctrl + Shift + P.**

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply Shaeel, I believed I have embedded it as a html document. Here is a preview of my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvzmxv3g2b7073q/bandicam%202020-10-10%2010-32-48-131.jpg?dl=0